# React Web App with Nginx not redirecting properly

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to deploy a React Web App on digital ocean using nginx.

My root points to the build folder in my git repo. This way I can update my app by git pull whenever I make a change.

At first, everything worked ok, but then I did a git pull and now I'm getting redirect errors or 500 errors. I'm not sure what happened.

If I open the site in the browser to the home page, it just shows a blank white screen. If I try accessing a subdomain, it gives a 500 internal error.

My sites-available/default file looks like:

```html
server {
    server_name portal.productive.city www.portal.productive.city;
    root /www/Productive-Website/my-app/build;
    index index.html index.htm;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

When I check the error-log I keep seeing

> 2018/08/31 13:32:26 [error] 29118#29118: *13 rewrite or internal
>   redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php",
>   client: 74.105.149.67, server: portal.productive.city, request: "GET
>   /signin/signin HTTP/1.1", host: "www.portal.productive.city",
>   referrer: "https://www.portal.productive.city/service-worker.js"

If I run nginx -t it says my config is ok and successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `index.php` doesn't exists on `/www/Productive-Website/my-app/build` maybe it should be a `.html` or `.htm` file? This makes your webserver try to render `index.php` and because it doesn't exists, you get redirected to `index.php`. If that is the case it would happen on any path.

Edit that file so that your location file looks like:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri?$args $uri/ $uri.html?$args /index.html?$args;
}
```

This means, "When receiving a request, search for a file matching `$uri OR $uri/ OR $uri.html` and if none of those works, render `/index.html?$args`". This means your React app should manage all errors on `/index.html`, so adequate your application accordingly.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Any reason why I'd still be getting 500 internal server error? The white page is gone but the 500 server error happens every time now. Is this something I need to deal with on the React App?