# 500 internal server error Nginx running react app

Tags: nginx

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52117509/3080828) answer, I have my nginx server set up like so:

```html
server {
    server_name portal.productive.city www.portal.productive.city;
    root /www/Productive-Website/my-app/build;
    index index.html index.htm;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
    location / {
       try_files $uri?$args $uri/ $uri.html?$args /index.html?$args;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

My other server (in the same file) (created by lets-encrypt) is:

```html
server {
    if ($host = www.portal.productive.city) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = portal.productive.city) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name portal.productive.city www.portal.productive.city;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

When I try to go to: [www.portal.productive.city](https://www.portal.productive.city) or [www.portal.productive.city/signin](https://www.portal.productive.city/signin) I get a **500 Internal Server Error**

My error-log file looks like:

> 2018/08/31 14:43:08 [error] 29581#29581: *25 rewrite or internal
>   redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html",
>   client: 74.105.149.67, server: portal.productive.city, request: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "www.portal.productive.city"
>
> 2018/08/31 14:43:08 [error] 29581#29581: *26 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while
>   internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 74.105.149.67,
>   server: portal.productive.city, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "www.portal.productive.city", referrer:
>   "https://www.portal.productive.city/"

The favicon.ico exists under `path/to/repo/build`

Edit: I cleared cache and restructured the server as follows:

```html
server {
    server_name portal.productive.city www.portal.productive.city;
    root /www/Productive-Website/my-app/build;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri?$args $uri/ $uri.html?$args /index.html?$args;
    }

    listen 80;
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri?$args;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The error-file is now:

> 2018/08/31 15:17:54 [error] 29789#29789: *17 rewrite or internal 
>   redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html",
>   client: 74.105.149.67, server: portal.productive.city, request: "GET
>   /? HTTP/1.1", host: "www.portal.productive.city"
>
> 2018/08/31 15:17:54
>   [error] 29789#29789: *18 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while
>   internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 74.105.149.67,
>   server: portal.productive.city, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "www.portal.productive.city", referrer:
>   "https://www.portal.productive.city/?"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have 2 server files with the same `server_name`, this makes your configuration harder to find. And, if by chance you configure both of them to listen to the same ports, it will confuse NGINX on which one to render. First, move them into the same one and redirect based on `$scheme` instead of `$host`. But that is not the real issue. You've got an redirect that is looping because it matches every request ending with '/'

```
server {
    server_name portal.productive.city www.portal.productive.city;
    root /www/Productive-Website/my-app/build;
    index index.html index.htm;
    # rewrite ^/(.*)/$ $1 permanent; Your REAL problem is here. You've got an redirect that is looping because it matches every request ending with '/'
    location / {
        try_files $uri?$args $uri/ $uri.html?$args /index.html?$args;
    }
    listen 80;
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri?$args
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.productive.city/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The https redirect like this means: "If the `$scheme` is not 'https', redirect to `https://$host$request_uri?$args`". Which translates to: "`https://` address on the same host, on the same path and whith the same URL arguments used on the access".

Comment: The servers are in the same file (default). Just want to clarify that. I edited my question to add that bit

Comment: Now it redirects to https://www.portal.productive.city/? and I still get 500 internal error. Check my edit to see my new setup of my server as well as error-file

Comment: why does the return 301 have $host? Should that be $scheme?

Comment: How would I monitor that?

Comment: Yes same error. I tried commenting out the if($scheme..) and I removed it completely. I then restarted nginx and cleared the cache. Same error

Comment: Let me check. That could be. I should remove that if it exists? Better to have redirection occur in the server?

Comment: Let NGINX handle any kind of redirect that is not directly related to your business logic.